# Is there any way to get the underlying reasonCode when using "message queuing" C API under windows?

Tags: windows, ibm-mq

While I'd love to be talking directly to MQSeries, I have to go through Window's Message Queuing C API for this application. Is there any way to fetch the actual MQSeries completionCode and reasonCode when an error is returned?

The API I'm referring to has functions like MQOpenQueue and MQSendMessage.

Comment: Are you using MSMQ and MSMQ-MQSeries Bridge?  You can directly interface with IBM WMQ using the MQI. Refer to the application programming guide on where to start. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.mon.doc%2Fq037480_.htm

Comment: I said in the question I can't directly access the MQSeries API.

Answer (score 0):

> The API I'm referring to has functions like MQOpenQueue and
>   MQSendMessage.

Those are function calls for Microsoft's Message Queuing (MSMQ).  They have nothing to do with WebSphere MQ (aka MQSeries).  From MSDN at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700112(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> This section describes the functions, properties, structures, error
>   and warning codes, and the COM components provided by the Message
>   Queuing (MSMQ) API.

As someone suggested, if you want to use WebSphere MQ (not MSMQ) then use the WebSphere MQ API. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q025700_.htm